# yarn run node very slow when no internet access

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I frequently work in intranet environment which has no internet access. I found out that yarn run node becomes extremely slow, which takes about 1 minute in offline environment. However, if I run the node without yarn, the execution time will be less than 1 second. Below is the full comparison:

version

```sh
yarn -v # 1.19.1
node -v # v10.16.3
```

package.json

```
{
    ...
    "scripts" : {
        "nodehelp" : "node --help"
    }
    ...
}
```

Execute node with different scenarios.

```sh
time node --help # online
real    0m0.115s
user    0m0.082s
sys     0m0.027s

time node --help # offline
real    0m0.325s
user    0m0.089s
sys     0m0.090s

time yarn nodehelp # online
real    0m9.656s
user    0m0.474s
sys     0m0.210s

time yarn nodehelp # offline, hang 1 minute!!!
real    1m0.666s
user    0m0.436s
sys     0m0.126s
```

Is it because of background have calls that require internet access. If yes, how to disable it? Or is there any other workaround?